# How can one obtain both non-repudiation and digital signature certificates?

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, pki

For a Public Key Infrastructure (PKI) client, it is required to obtain both non-repudiation and digital signature certificates. The following code has been implemented to obtain those certificates:

```
keyStore.load(null, null);
Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases();
while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
    String alias = aliases.nextElement();
        if (keyStore.isKeyEntry(alias)) {
            java.security.cert.Certificate certificate = keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
        }
}
```

However, both digital and non-repudiation certificates have the same alias. so when `keystore.getCertificate` was called, the system will always return the first result, although in the certmgr.msc window, it was observed that there were 2 certificates, and the LOOP block executed two times, but the system will always return duplicate result from the first certificate. How can one resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot really have two different entries with the same alias. But this is how you can get list of all first level certificates from the key store as a list

```
List<Certificate> certificates = new ArrayList<Certificate>();
Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases();
while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
    String alias = aliases.nextElement();
    Certificate certificate = keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
    if (certificate != null) {
        certificates.add(certificate);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm definatly not asking the question about how to distinguish the non repudiation and digital signature. What I'm asking about is the process of extracting certificate, so would you please suggest a way to load both certificates, because the way I'm doing it right now, detects two certificates, but loads the same object on each iteration

Comment: I've updated my answer, so now list will contain all certificates the key store has.

Comment: That's the right idea, but unfortunately, this won't list all the certificates in the store, due to an implementation detail (bug?) in the Windows store...

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about `certmgr.msc` and using `keyStore.load(null, null)`, I presume you're using the `WINDOWS-ROOT` or `WINDOWS-MY` keystore, from the [SunMSCAPI provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/security-137537.html#1).

Unfortunately, there is an [issue with this provider](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6483657) because it can re-used the same alias for multiple entries, thereby making it difficult or impossible to access some certificates.

The alias used by this keystore is in fact the "friendly name" of the certificate (in the MS-CAPI terminology). While the friendly name doesn't need to be unique in the Windows certificate store, the alias name needs to be.

Presumably, because you seem talking about two distinct certificates for the same entity but with different purposes, they're likely to use the same friendly name by default.

Once way to work around this problem is to identify your certificates with different friendly names in the Windows store: in `certmgr.msc`, select the certificate, right-click, choose "Properties" and change its "Friendly Name".

If you have two distinct certificates (for different key usages or any other reason) that have unique friendly names, they should show up with different alias names in your KeyStore then.